# What is proper Xpath for below element?

Tags: xpath

I have tried below Xpath but it's not working for the mentioned element

```
//span[@text(),'Accounts')]
//span[Contains(@text() ='Accounts']
//span[text()='Accounts'][1]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`@text()` is syntactically valid but will never select anything - you're looking for text nodes on the attribute axis, and the only thing ever found on the attribute axis is an attribute node. (When I see this kind of construct, I get the impression you're groping in the dark, and haven't found a decent reference that you can consult.)

`//span[text()='Accounts']` will select the required node, but it isn't the first child of its parent, so adding the predicate `[1]` causes it to be rejected.

You want `(//span[text()='Accounts'])[1]`.

Comment: Not working with the suggested Xpath

Comment: Then you're going to have to provide a repro - we need to see the full XML document, provided as text rather than a cropped image.